# Turn string into float with two decimal places

Tags: python, floating-point

I am trying to turn `str '3'` into `float 3.00`

```
va = '%.2f' % float('3')
print va
print isinstance(va, float)

3.00
False

---

vb = float('%.2f' % float('3'))
print vb
print isinstance(vb, float)

3.0
True
```

I need code that outputs

```
3.00  # correct decimal places
True  # is float
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing float values with their string representation. `float(3)` is enough, and whenever you need to print one, use formatting.

```
va = float('3')
print format(va, '.2f')
print isinstance(va, float)
```

`float` objects themselves have *no concept* of a number of decimal places to track.

Comment: I am starting with string '3', not number 3.

Comment: @onepiece: that makes no difference to the answer though.

Comment: Actually I see what you're saying.  `float()` is for `float`, `format()` is for `string`.  Used for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `float("3")` to achieve that but notice that a `float` does not have a specific number of digits after the decimal point; that's more a feature of outputting a `float` using string formatting.  So you can use `'%.2f' % float("3")` to see your `float` value with two decimal digits.

Your tests were all flawed in several aspects.

`va = '%.2f' % float('3')` created a `str` which looked like a float, not a `float`.

`vb = float('%.2f' % float('3'))` created a decent `float` but your printing test `print vb` then did not format the `float` to using two decimal digits after the point.  It just used the default formatting (which prints one trailing `.0` to make clear that this is not an `int`).

Comment: So basically for string `'3'`, I can only display `'3.00'` as a string?

Comment: If you want to display something, it _always_ has to be a string (unless we talk about graphics).  The internal representation of a float is quite different from that `3.0`, so anything with a `3` in front is a string of characters, and to display this, you first have to convert your `float` into such a string.  Only when using `print vb` this is done implicitly (using default parameters for the format).